# My EA doesn't place Short orders or execute my trailing stop functionality, what did I do wrong?

Tags: mql4

This EA is based off the turtle system of Richard Dennis, using mostly Donchian channels. I don't have the indicator installed on mql4, but I just worked with the highest highs and lowest lows of the specific periods. I did test to see if these values are correct and I've used most of the functions in other EA's without any issues.
The only new function I've written is the CloseByMagicNum() function, which is supposed to check for a specific magic number and symbol and close all orders with them. This is to track the trailing stop with the 10-day Donchian channels and I intend to use this EA on multiple pairs and commodities once I get it to work properly on one symbol, so this function needs to check the symbol as well.

Please be nice as I am a completely new trader and programmer (Self-taught on both accounts)

```
#property copyright "Hansen Pieterse"
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict


input int DonPeriodExit = 10;
input int DonPeriodS1 = 20;
input int DonPeriodS2 = 55;
input int TimeframeIndex = 4;

input int ATRPeriod = 20;
input int ATRShift = 0;

input int RRR = 5;
input int SLMultiplier = 2;
input int MaxLossPerc = 2;
input double GlobalTakeProfit = 10;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
  
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
  
  /*if(GetAccountProfit() > GlobalTakeProfit)
  {
   CloseOrders();
  }*/
     double ATRValue = iATR(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),ATRPeriod,ATRShift);
     double SLLength = ATRValue * SLMultiplier;
     
     double CurrentAsk = MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_ASK);
     double CurrentBid = MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_BID);
     
     double DonUpperSystem1 = iHigh(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),(iHighest(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),MODE_HIGH,DonPeriodS1,0)));
     double DonUpperSystem2 = iHigh(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),(iHighest(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),MODE_HIGH,DonPeriodS2,0)));
     double DonLowerSystem1 = iLow(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),(iLowest(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),MODE_LOW,DonPeriodS1,0)));
     double DonLowerSystem2 = iLow(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),(iLowest(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),MODE_LOW,DonPeriodS2,0)));
     
     
     double DonLowerExit = iLow(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),(iLowest(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),MODE_LOW,DonPeriodExit,0)));
     double DonUpperExit = iHigh(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),(iHighest(Symbol(),GetTimeframeInt(TimeframeIndex),MODE_HIGH,DonPeriodExit,0)));
        
     //Check Open orders & Check if Traiing stop is reached
     if(checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(1)         &&
        CurrentBid < DonLowerExit)
     {
      CloseByMagicNum(1,Symbol());
     }   
        
     //LONG Conditions
      if(CurrentAsk > DonUpperSystem1           &&
        !checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(1)
        )
        
        {
         double Long_SL =  CurrentAsk - SLLength;
         double Long_TP = ((CurrentAsk-Long_SL)*RRR)+CurrentAsk;
         double Long_Lots = RiskLots(Symbol(),CurrentAsk,Long_SL,MaxLossPerc);
         int Long_ID = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,Long_Lots,CurrentAsk,0,Long_SL,Long_TP,NULL,1);
        }
        
      if(CurrentAsk > DonUpperSystem2           &&
        !checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(1)
        )
        
        {
         double Long_SL =  CurrentAsk - SLLength;
         double Long_TP = ((CurrentAsk-Long_SL)*RRR)+CurrentAsk;
         double Long_Lots = RiskLots(Symbol(),CurrentAsk,Long_SL,MaxLossPerc);
         int Long_ID = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,Long_Lots,CurrentAsk,0,Long_SL,Long_TP,NULL,1);
        }
        
     //Check Open orders & Check if Traiing stop is reached
     if(checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(-1)         &&
        CurrentAsk > DonUpperExit)
     {
      CloseByMagicNum(-1,Symbol());
     }   
        
        
      //SHORT Conditions
      if(CurrentBid < DonLowerSystem1             &&
         !checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(-1)
        )
        
        {
         double Short_SL = CurrentBid + SLLength;
         double Short_TP = CurrentBid - ((Short_SL - CurrentBid)*RRR);
         double Short_Lots = RiskLots(Symbol(),CurrentBid,Short_SL,MaxLossPerc);
         int Short_ID = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,Short_Lots,CurrentBid,0,Short_SL,Short_TP,NULL,-1);
        }

      if(CurrentBid < DonLowerSystem2             &&
         !checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(-1)
        )
        
        {
         double Short_SL = CurrentBid + SLLength;
         double Short_TP = CurrentBid - ((Short_SL - CurrentBid)*RRR);
         double Short_Lots = RiskLots(Symbol(),CurrentBid,Short_SL,MaxLossPerc);
         int Short_ID = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,Short_Lots,CurrentBid,0,Short_SL,Short_TP,NULL,-1);
        }
  }


//FUNCTIONS-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double GetPipValue() // GET THE VALUE FOR ONE PIP IN TERMS OF THE CURRENT CURRENCY PAIR 
{
   if(_Digits >= 4)
   {
      return 0.0001;
   }
   else
   {
      return 0.01;
   }
}

double GetMSL(string symbol)
   {
      double MSLPips = MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_STOPLEVEL);
      double MSL = MSLPips * GetPipValue();
      
      return MSL;
   }

string GetCurrencyPairString(int index)
{
   string FXPAIRS[37];

   FXPAIRS[0] = "EURUSD";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[1] = "USDJPY";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[2] = "GBPUSD";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[3] = "USDCHF";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[4] = "AUDUSD";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[5] = "USDCAD";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[6] = "NZDUSD";  //MAJOR
   FXPAIRS[7] = "EURGBP";  //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[8] = "EURCHF";  //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[9] = "EURJPY";  //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[10] = "GBPJPY"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[11] = "CHFJPY"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[12] = "AUDJPY"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[13] = "CADJPY"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[14] = "NZDJPY"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[15] = "AUDNZD"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[16] = "AUDCHF"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[17] = "GBPCHF"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[18] = "CADCHF"; //MINOR
   FXPAIRS[19] = "EURTRY"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[20] = "USDTRY"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[21] = "USDMXN"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[22] = "USDZAR"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[23] = "USDHKD"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[24] = "USDSGD"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[25] = "USDTHB"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[26] = "USDSEK"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[27] = "USDDKK"; //EXOTIC
   FXPAIRS[28] = "EURAUD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[29] = "EURCAD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[30] = "EURNZD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[31] = "GBPAUD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[32] = "GBPCAD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[33] = "GBPNZD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[34] = "NZDCAD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[35] = "AUDCAD"; //Extra
   FXPAIRS[36] = "NZDCHF"; //Extra
   
   
   
   return FXPAIRS[index];
}

int GetTimeframeInt(int index)
{

int TimeFrames[10];

TimeFrames[0] = 0;
TimeFrames[1] = 1;
TimeFrames[2] = 5;
TimeFrames[3] = 15;
TimeFrames[4] = 30;
TimeFrames[5] = 60;
TimeFrames[6] = 240;
TimeFrames[7] = 1440;
TimeFrames[8] = 10080;
TimeFrames[9] = 432001;

return TimeFrames[index];
}

bool checkOpenOrdersByMagicNumber(int magicNum)
  {
   int openOrders = OrdersTotal();
   for(int i = 0; i < openOrders; i++)
      {
         if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS)==true)
         {
            if(OrderMagicNumber()==magicNum) 
            {
               return true;
            }
         }
      }
     return false;
  }

void CloseOrders()
{
   // Update the exchange rates before closing the orders.
   RefreshRates();
   // Log in the terminal the total of orders, current and past.
   Print(OrdersTotal());
      
   // Start a loop to scan all the orders.
   // The loop starts from the last order, proceeding backwards; Otherwise it would skip some orders.
   for (int i = (OrdersTotal() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
   {
      // If the order cannot be selected, throw and log an error.
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES) == false)
          {
         Print("ERROR - Unable to select the order - ", GetLastError());
         break;
      } 

      // Create the required variables.
      // Result variable - to check if the operation is successful or not.
      bool res = false;
      
      // Allowed Slippage - the difference between current price and close price.
      int Slippage = 0;
      
      // Bid and Ask prices for the instrument of the order.
      double BidPrice = MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID);
      double AskPrice = MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_ASK);

      // Closing the order using the correct price depending on the type of order.
      if (OrderType() == OP_BUY)
          {
         res = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), BidPrice, Slippage);
      }
      else if (OrderType() == OP_SELL)
          {
         res = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), AskPrice, Slippage);
      }
      
      // If there was an error, log it.
      if (res == false) Print("ERROR - Unable to close the order - ", OrderTicket(), " - ", GetLastError());
   }
}

void CloseByMagicNum(int MagicNum, string SymbolString)
{
   // Update the exchange rates before closing the orders.
   RefreshRates();
   // Log in the terminal the total of orders, current and past.
   Print(OrdersTotal());
      
   // Start a loop to scan all the orders.
   // The loop starts from the last order, proceeding backwards; Otherwise it would skip some orders.
   for (int i = (OrdersTotal() - 1); i >= 0; i--)
   {
      // If the order cannot be selected, throw and log an error.
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES) == false)
          {
         Print("ERROR - Unable to select the order - ", GetLastError());
         break;
      } 

      // Create the required variables.
      // Result variable - to check if the operation is successful or not.
      bool res = false;
      
      // Allowed Slippage - the difference between current price and close price.
      int Slippage = 0;
      
      // Bid and Ask prices for the instrument of the order.
      double BidPrice = MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID);
      double AskPrice = MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_ASK);

      // Closing the order using the correct price depending on the type of order.
      if (OrderType() == OP_BUY        &&
          OrderMagicNumber()==MagicNum && 
          OrderSymbol()==SymbolString
      )
          {
         res = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), BidPrice, Slippage);
      }
      else if (OrderType() == OP_SELL  &&
          OrderMagicNumber()==MagicNum && 
          OrderSymbol()==SymbolString)
          {
         res = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), AskPrice, Slippage);
      }
      
      // If there was an error, log it.
      if (res == false) Print("ERROR - Unable to close the order - ", OrderTicket(), " - ", GetLastError());
   }
}

double GetAccountProfit()
{
   double FloatingProfit = AccountProfit();
   double Equity = AccountEquity();
   double ProfitPerc = NormalizeDouble(((FloatingProfit/Equity)*100),2);
   
   return ProfitPerc;
}

double RiskLots( string symbol, double Entry, double StopLoss, double RiskPercentage ) {

   
   double tickSize      = SymbolInfoDouble( symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE );
   double tickValue     = SymbolInfoDouble( symbol, SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE );
   double point         = SymbolInfoDouble( symbol, SYMBOL_POINT );
   double ticksPerPoint = tickSize / point;
   double pointValue    = tickValue / ticksPerPoint;
   
   double RiskPercentageDecimal = RiskPercentage/100;
   double riskAmount = AccountBalance()*RiskPercentageDecimal;
   double riskPoints = MathAbs(Entry-StopLoss)/tickSize;
   double riskLots   = riskAmount / ( pointValue * riskPoints );
   
   if(riskLots < MarketInfo(symbol,MODE_MINLOT))
   {return MarketInfo(symbol,MODE_MINLOT);}
   return ( riskLots );
}
```